# Decorator Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, methods, this, decorator

Why doesn't typescript's function decorator print this of the class in which it decorates the method?

```js
interface IUserService {
    users: number;
    get(): void;
}

class UserService implements IUserService {
    users: number = 100;

    @methodDecorator()
    get() {
        console.log(this.users) // output underfined
        console.log(1); // all id okey, output is 1
    }
}

function methodDecorator(throwError?: boolean) {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, decriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>) => {
        const oldFunc = decriptor.value;
        decriptor.value = async () => {
            try {
                await oldFunc?.apply(target);
            } catch (err) {
                if (throwError) {
                    console.log('кидаем дальше!');
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    if (err instanceof Error) {
                        console.log('Попалась ошибка!');
                        console.log(err.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    return decriptor
    };
}

function methodDecorator(throwError?: boolean) {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, decriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>) => {
        const oldFunc = decriptor.value as ()=>any;
        decriptor.value = async () => {
      console.log('I am decorator!')
      await oldFunc.apply(target)
        };
    return decriptor
    };
}

new UserService().get()
```

This is output:
`I am decorator!`
`undefined`  // why?? i used .apply !//
`1`
`

I don't understand why it doesn't output this.users ?? I use apply and pass the target, everything is as indicated in the guides, but in the end it gives ungerfined... The object that owns the decorated method must be passed to the target

Answer (score 0):

`target` inside the decorator will be the class itself not the instance. You need to define the replacement function as a regular `function` expression not an arrow function and use the `this` that function gets called with:

```
interface IUserService {
    users: number;
    get(): void;
}

class UserService implements IUserService {
    users: number = 100;

    @methodDecorator()
    get() {
        console.log(this.users) // output underfined
        console.log(1); // all id okey, output is 1
    }
}


function methodDecorator(throwError?: boolean) {
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, decriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>) => {
        const oldFunc = decriptor.value as () => any;
        
        decriptor.value = async function () {  // Not an arrow function 
            console.log('I am decorator!')
            await oldFunc.apply(this) // use the this
        };
        return decriptor
    };
}

new UserService().get()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0DK0BuwSyA3gLABQy1yArtlJgFzIi0C2ARtANyU3IA5hDAAKAJQt8Ae2AATPhQC+lSggA2cTJmRZcBIimDsADuojsI4HRgZ4ohYuSo160Zqw7coyALzIARgAGIMV+GgABSzAAC2k5ABEIBGkoODBUiXDqYTFxUmyBZBSQTGlzADp1aUFRWOBMCrdGfIB6VuRpWjATbroQOWgYUAg5QoESssrq2oDxHmR25Dh1dWR5ToBrCABPABpO7t6wdZ0AwpVlVQpKGFoQBDBgaRBkaLjE5NT0zNioaQA7gBRKD-KAAfhYnGk5QgcBA+WcAigIloUFedTgUFyLAA8pwAFbJMAHEz-EzQMA7ADSuxYmDAUFAgmQAB9kJgdlxygdBggmSYMlAWAAVHYUuQABXJlJ2SUw-OAgtSAB5RBUNVjBB54TsANoAXXyvgAfMsQDsTcazUiitRJidynIAGL3BB+ZB8gVCir4Fa0FBaZASPxm3VhFx2r1Kn1+9QBj1aHYPZB3B5PF7BxHUJYAOWkJ3hy1BgNTbozr3GduKLymECqNVEAHJUMt2J6vmkhQBCJviKt2uAAuDAR3qF1uipwExmHZ1GINNodNzIWIoeo6MBwGInNdl9PPV7DnQIFbmOTIAGjmID5BKRTV5AosBo17R5VQC6KS6UEAQAG6HYBhIBIFS5BIQA)